# What does "left instead of right mean "?

Tags: american-english

[image: its in stephen king novel frm green mile]
Its frm stephen king novel green mile

Comment: It means literally to make a left turn when she got to the desk instead of a right turn.  Which way she turned obviously had implications on what kinds of interaction the speaker would have or would not have with Bev.

Answer (score 4):

In the preceding text, the author told the reader that Beverley was beautiful, that she had been sentenced to death for murdering her cheating husband, and, finally, that her death sentence had been commuted (reduced) to life imprisonment. In the sentence starting "I was glad..." King conveys three pieces of information: the narrator (a guard) was glad that this had happened;  the guard found Beverley attractive - he describes her motion in terms of her posterior ("ass"); an immediate result of the commutation was that Beverley turned left instead of right when reaching the duty desk. At the end of the sentence, King appends "let me tell you" as an intensifier of "I was glad" at the start. The underlying reason for the left (and not right) turn is given a little later in this first chapter. The prison block is laid out so that the cells for condemned prisoners are reached by turning right at the end of the central corridor, and the cells for the other prisoners are reached by turning left.